# Automatic print any hyperlink into PDF

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

all,

I have several recipes that I store in G-Drive and are linked to the google sheet.

When you open the "Print_catalog" tab, you see a list of recipes.
I used to print the catalog using the "Print all" script and I will have the combined PDF of Print_catalog.

But since I'm adding the recipes into the catalog, is it possible to have the hyperlink also converted to PDF once I hit the print all button?

Thanks in advance for your help.

I wonder if the hyperlink (recipes) can be automatic downloaded as PDF rather than manually download.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q1orpHAJJvTUu3b0JoehR-9iOzDtvsPu457QzPDJ58A/edit#gid=1432595422

New info: @Cooper : I'm able to compile all the catalog except converting the each of the link to PDF https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/15wH63uWUsg9ZmkJTHcfQKbcPnX7ecdin.
Is it possible to have it like the end result that I wanted like this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AsApiC7bM87iAJ2ysR8ikbppyFtVwdCr/view?usp=sharing

Thank you so much.

Comment: I don't know the complete answer for your question but I know that you can open any google document (or sheet) file as pdf just manipulating it's link. Maybe it helps you smoehow. You add export=pdf after google ID in the url. For example link to your sheet is: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q1orpHAJJvTUu3b0JoehR-9iOzDtvsPu457QzPDJ58A/export=pdf

Comment: To answer your question I would have to know more about what you're doing but unfortunately I won't follow links to spreadsheets.

Comment: @Cooper this is the end result that I wanted <https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AsApiC7bM87iAJ2ysR8ikbppyFtVwdCr/view?usp=sharing>

Comment: I am not sure I completely understand what you want to achieve - so essentially you would want to print the PDF recipe just by accessing a link? @Kat

Comment: @ale13 : yes, if that's possible